# How do I read a specific part of text file in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I am developing a *pizzeria system* in C, it has a menu in a text file, I would like to know how I get a menu item by entering its ID.
Below is the example file:

```
ID : 1
Nome da Pizza : Gostosona
Ingredientes : Palmito, Presunto, Queijo e catupiri
Valor Grande R$: 30,00
Valor Broto R$: 21,00
==========================================
ID : 2
Nome da Pizza : Frango Alho
Ingredientes : Frango,Alho e Catupiry
Valor Grande R$: 30,00
Valor Broto R$: 21,00
```

I would like to know how I only get the information from the first ID based on the fact that ==== would be the delimiter between one pizza and another

the code I've done so far it looks for something in the line and returns only that line and not what is below it

```c
char Termino[100];
    while(Arquivo && fgets(Termino, sizeof(Termino), Arquivo))
    {
        if (strstr(Termino, "ID : "))
            printf("%s", Termino);
        else if (strstr(Termino, "Nome da Pizza : "))
            printf("%s", Termino);
        else if (strstr(Termino, "Ingredientes : "))
            printf("%s", Termino);
        else if (strstr(Termino, "Valor Grande R$: "))
            printf("%s", Termino);
        else if (strstr(Termino, "Valor Broto R$: "))
            printf("%s\n", Termino);

    }
    system("pause");
    if(Arquivo)
    fclose(Arquivo);
```

Comment: You need to seek to the right byte, then read. You either need to index your file (i.e have the byte offset for each entries), or you'll need to find that offset everytime, based on a search key (Find "ID :).

Comment: Let me understand: you are asking how to parse ID line in order to print only data for desired ID?

Comment: You should read the entire file into an array of structures. Then search the array.

Comment: exacly, 
I was wondering how do I type so id and the information below appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe, your second attempt is better, but still attempting to read/convert more than required. Before looking at an approach, let's look at two general points, (1) Avoid using *Magic-Numbers* in your code, and (2) do not *Hardcode Filenames*.

```
FILE *Arquivo = fopen("Cardapio.txt","r");   /* Hardcoded Filename */
...
   char Termino[100];     /* 100 is a Magic-Number */
```

`main()` takes arguments that allows you to pass the filename as an argument to `main()`, or you can take the filename as user-input the same as you do `inputID`. Instead:

```
#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXN  128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument */
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* open/validate file open for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
        perror ("fopen-argv[1]");
        return 1;
    }
```

In any instance where you need to display a menu, simply loop continually until some exit condition is met, e.g.

```
for (;;) {  /* loop continually until quit entered */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    int id = 0, inputid = 0;

    rewind (fp);    /* rewind file and prompt */
    fputs ("\nCardapio\n-----------------------------------"
            "---------------------------------------------\n"
            "enter ID: ", stdout);
    fflush (stdout);    /* flush stdout (optional but recommended) */

    /* read user input & test if "quit" entered */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || strcmp (buf, "quit\n") == 0)
        break;
```

(**note:** how the `'\n'` resulting from the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and read and included in `buf` by `fgets()` is part of the comparison. Without it, you would need to remove the trailing `'\n'` before comparison.)

If the user did not type `"quit"`, then convert the input to an integer value using `sscanf`. (if error handling is needed use `strtol` to instead of `sscanf` as `sscanf` can do no more than indicate a conversion took place, but cannot tell you anything about why it failed in the event of failure). For your case, `sscanf` is sufficient, e.g.

```
    /* convert input to integer & validate conversion */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &inputid) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        break;
    }
```

With a valid `inputid`, you are ready to loop through the file scanning for a matching `id`. The same `fgets()` followed by `sscanf` works equally well here:

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read searching for inputid */
        if (sscanf (buf, "ID : %d", &id) == 1 && id == inputid)
            break;
```

(**note:** the conditional (1) validates conversion to integer, and (2) compares to `inputid` and if both are true, your pizza has been found)

To determine whether the pizza was found or you reached `EOF`, you can simply check if the `id` differs from `inputid` (a reverse (or negative) of the prior conditional), e.g.

```
    if (id != inputid) {    /* if inputid not found warn/continue */
        fputs ("error: ID not found.\n", stderr);
        continue;
    }
```

Now you have confirmed that the `inputid` was found in the file and your *file position indicator* is set ready to read the detail of the pizza associated with the `inputid`. Here you can simply loop reading and outputting each line until the first character is `'='` or `EOF` is encountered, e.g.

```
    /* if inputid found, output pizza details */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && *buf != '=')
        fputs (buf, stdout);
}
```

That is really all you need if you are using the file as your storage. (in practice you would want to use either a fixed or dynamically allocated array of struct to read all data into memory in a single read to reduce subsequent lookup times by orders of magnitude) All that remains is closing the file (which will happen on program exit, but is a good habit to get into for when your file handling is not followed by program exit).

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXN  128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* use filename provided as 1st argument */
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* open/validate file open for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
        perror ("fopen-argv[1]");
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until quit entered */
        char buf[MAXC] = "";
        int id = 0, inputid = 0;

        rewind (fp);    /* rewind file and prompt */
        fputs ("\nCardapio\n-----------------------------------"
                "---------------------------------------------\n"
                "enter ID: ", stdout);
        fflush (stdout);    /* flush stdout (optional but recommended) */

        /* read user input & test if "quit" entered */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || strcmp (buf, "quit\n") == 0)
            break;

        /* convert input to integer & validate conversion */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &inputid) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }

        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read searching for inputid */
            if (sscanf (buf, "ID : %d", &id) == 1 && id == inputid)
                break;

        if (id != inputid) {    /* if inputid not found warn/continue */
            fputs ("error: ID not found.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        /* if inputid found, output pizza details */
        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && *buf != '=')
            fputs (buf, stdout);
    }

    fclose (fp);    /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your file stored in `dat/pizza.txt`, you would run your program as follows. (I've adjusted the output formatting slightly, change as desired)

```
$ ./bin/pizzasystem dat/pizza.txt

Cardapio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter ID: 1
Nome da Pizza : Gostosona
Ingredientes : Palmito, Presunto, Queijo e catupiri
Valor Grande R$: 30,00
Valor Broto R$: 21,00

Cardapio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter ID: 2
Nome da Pizza : Frango Alho
Ingredientes : Frango,Alho e Catupiry
Valor Grande R$: 30,00
Valor Broto R$: 21,00

Cardapio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter ID: 3
error: ID not found.

Cardapio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter ID: quit
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Glad it helped. There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* with C. There is nothing you can't do with the language, it's just a matter of learning enough to learn how (the learning part actually never stops...)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is basically retrieve id number. In this case I use `atoi()` but there are other possibilities.

Another requirement is being sure of source file correctness. **Any further sanity check is up to you**.

```
    char Termino[100];
    int curID = -1;
    while(Arquivo && fgets(Termino, sizeof(Termino), Arquivo))
    {
        if (strstr(Termino, "ID : "))
        {
            curID = atoi (Termino+strlen("ID : "));
            if ( curID == inputID )
                printf("%s", Termino);
        }
        else if( curID == inputID )
        {
            if (strstr(Termino, "Nome da Pizza : "))
                printf("%s", Termino);
            else if (strstr(Termino, "Ingredientes : "))
                printf("%s", Termino);
            else if (strstr(Termino, "Valor Grande R$: "))
                printf("%s", Termino);
            else if (strstr(Termino, "Valor Broto R$: "))
            {
                printf("%s\n", Termino);
                // After last field we can end file scanning
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
```

Basically you store the parsered ID to an integer variable and compare it to the `inputID`. Only on successful comparison you print ID, otherwise scan until the next ID row. After the last field of the given ID has been printed, no need to search anymore.